# What is the optimized way to fill table values based on it's previous columns values and from other table column values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert

```
CREATE TABLE TEST2
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Ratio INT
)
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Col1 INT,
    Col2 INT,
    Col3 INT
)
```

Now, I want to insert values in `table TEST` as

```
    INSERT INTO TEST
        (Col1, Col2, Col3)
    values
         (10, 
          col1, 
          col2 * (select Ratio 
                  from TEST2 T2 INNER JOIN TEST T 
                       ON T2.RowID = T.RowID)
         );
```

Above `query` is what I want.
How could we done above `insert` operation by using optimize way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want - if table `test` has N rows - to insert N more rows, with the values calculated from the join between the existing rows in `test` and `test2`.

You then need to use the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax and not the `INSERT ... VALUES`. Assuming that `test2` has a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(RowID)`, then the following will insert (max) N rows to `test`:

```
INSERT INTO TEST
    (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT
    10, 
    t.col1, 
    t.col2 * t2.ratio 
FROM test2 AS t2 
  INNER JOIN test AS t 
  ON t2.RowID = t.RowID ;
```

If you want to update the existing N rows, you need an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. Assuming the rows have already values in `col1` and `col2`:

```
UPDATE t
SET
    Col1 = 10, 
    Col2 = t.Col1, 
    Col3 = t.Col2 * t2.Ratio         
FROM test2 AS t2 
  INNER JOIN test AS t
  ON t2.RowID = t.RowID ;
```

The third assignment should probably be changed, if only `Col1` has values and you want to update both `Col2` and `Col3`, based on the `Col1` values, to:

```
    Col3 = t.Col1 * t2.Ratio
```